# How do I generate the documentation that I've coded as Xml in the C# ?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, documentation

When you code Xml documentation in your C# code (not sure if VB supports this or not), like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the identity of the Mail Server that is to be used to send the email.
/// </summary>
public string MailServer
{
    get { return _mailServer; }
    set { _mailServer = value; }
}
```

The Xml in the three-slash comment gets used in Intellisense, but it seems that in an earlier version of Visual Studio (2003 I think) there was a tool that would go through the code and assemble all these elements (along with the object names, etc) to form a complete Xml document.  I can't find this tool in Visual Studio 2008, 2010 and 2012.

I'm excited to start learning how to use Sandcastle and all that, but this is going to take me some time, and I need this thing right now for some documentation I am trying to produce.

So the question is, since this tool was in VS once, is it still there but I just haven't been able to find it (obscurred)?  Or must I get an external tool (preferably free)?

Comment: [How to: Generate XML Documentation for a Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x4sa0ak0(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: So why don't you make that an Answer?  It definitely answers the question for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The **Generate XML documentation** file property determines whether an
>   XML file will be generated during compilation. You set this property
>   on the **Build** page of the **Project Designer.** When this option is
>   selected, XML documentation is automatically emitted into an XML file,
>   which will have the same name as your project and the .xml extension.
>
> To generate an XML documentation file for a Visual C# project
>
> 1. With a project selected in Solution Explorer, on the **Project** menu, click **Propertie**s.
> 2. Click the **Build** tab.
> 3. On the Build page, select **XML documentation file**. By default, the file is created under the specified output path, for example,
>      "bin\Debug\Projectname.XML".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x4sa0ak0(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a Sandcastle builder that integrates right into Visual Studio now. It makes it easy as pie. http://shfb.codeplex.com/

Comment: That's a good answer, and in fact I downloaded this item yesterday, but haven't yet figured out how to use it.

Comment: You just install it and it adds a template (under installed templates from add project dialog) under Documentation. Add the Sandcastle Help File Builder project to the solution and the rest should be smooth sailing.